# Counter-example of function which is continuous on closed subspaces, but not continuous on whole space

Tags: general-topology

I have an exercise in general topology as follows:

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between topological spaces. Assume that $X=\cup _{i\in I} X_i$ with $X_i$ closed subsets of $X$, and $f|_{X_i}: X_i\rightarrow Y$ is continuous for every $i$. We can prove that if $I$ is finite, then $f$ is continuous on $X$. However, do we have a counter-example when $I$ is countable?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Take $X = Y = \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(0) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Now $f|_{\{x\}}$ is continuous (constant) for every $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and thus continuous. Now $\mathbb{Q} = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{Q}} \{x\}$ is a countable union but $f: \mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thank you! It's so simple than I expected!